# Incorrect Marker Placement on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Working on a map with multiple markers. For some reason all the markers are off by the same amount to the west of where the lat/long pair should be placing them.

See in action here: http://91chapel.arraydev.net/neighbourhood/

I have double checked long / lat on a number of markers, and it's definitely not a simple situation of lat long being wrong. Every marker is off to the west by the same amount. I don't think this is an anchor point issue, as the markers stay where they are when you zoom.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var locations = [
    ['Gabriola Island Ferry Terminal', 49.166102, -123.930666, 'transportation'],
    ['Newcastle Island Ferry',49.171953, -123.937345, 'transportation'],
    ['Harbour Air Seaplanes', 49.168181, -123.935382, 'transportation'],
    ['Budget Car & Truck Rental', 49.1669641,-123.9366057, 'transportation'],
    ['Prideaux Exchange Transit Terminal', 49.1642815,-123.945626, 'transportation'],
    ['RBC Bank', 49.1665076,-123.9398008, 'financial services'],
    ['Scotiabank', 49.1652551,-123.9394705, 'financial services'],
    ['CIBC', 49.1644153,-123.9350475, 'financial services'],
    ['TD Canada Trust', 49.1644469,-123.9495123, 'financial services'],
    ['Coastal Community Credit Union', 49.1660125,-123.938417, 'financial services'],
    ['Old City Station Pub', 49.1668432,-123.9387767, 'nightlife'],
    ['Corner Lounge', 49.1664115,-123.9393155, 'nightlife'],
    ['The Queen’s', 49.1635335,-123.937801, 'nightlife'],
    ['Koncept Nightclub', 49.1658795,-123.939573, 'nightlife'],
    ['Evolve Nightclub', 49.1657932,-123.9398943, 'nightlife'],
    ['Level Two Dance Lounge', 49.1662832,-123.9400326, 'nightlife'],
    ['Man Lee Asian Grocery', 49.1649712,-123.9401409, 'shopping'],
    ['Thrifty Foods', 49.1642655,-123.9349063, 'shopping'],
    ['London Drugs', 49.1641759,-123.934868, 'shopping'],
    ['Port Place Mall', 49.1640022,-123.9358513, 'shopping'],
    ['Charlie’s Closet', 49.1650488,-123.9444328, 'shopping'],
    ['Funk Your Fashion', 49.1654641,-123.9392265, 'shopping'],
    ['NYLA', 49.1667314,-123.9391723, 'shopping'],
    ['Catwalk Fashions', 49.1646325,-123.9390433, 'shopping'],
    ['Cayo Fashions', 49.1651339,-123.9391418, 'shopping'],
    ['Flying Fish Kitchen & Gift', 49.1665315,-123.9390107, 'shopping'],
    ['McLean’s Specialty Foods', 49.1654499,-123.9444083, 'shopping'],
    ['Quintessential', 49.1652513,-123.9388586, 'shopping'],
    ['Coast Bastion', 49.1666265,-123.938257, 'accommodations'],
    ['Best Western Dorchester', 49.1672955,-123.938629, 'accommodations'],
    ['Painted Turtle Guesthouse', 49.1664115,-123.9393155, 'accommodations'],
    ['The Bee’s Knees Cafe', 49.1669051,-123.9431893, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Perkins Coffee', 49.1668764,-123.9391885, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['2 Chefs Affair', 49.1659377,-123.9392269, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Food Koma', 49.1662298,-123.9392601, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Sukkho Thai', 49.1659195,-123.9390989, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Mon Petit Choux', 49.1659685,-123.9388903, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Gabriel’s Cafe', 49.1650715,-123.939197, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Noodlebox', 49.1649529,-123.9360184, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Mambo Gourmet Pizza', 49.1636568,-123.938287, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Gina’s Mexican Cafe', 49.169037,-123.9411112, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Asteras Greek Cuisine', 49.1644365,-123.9433279, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Bistro Taiyo Japanese', 49.1649613,-123.9437265, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['La Stella Trattoria', 49.1651965,-123.943475, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Bocca Cafe', 49.1651885,-123.944584, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Pho A Dong Vietnamese', 49.1655617,-123.9446795, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Trollers Fish & Chips', 49.1673115,-123.936761, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Power House Living Foods', 49.1667119,-123.9391507, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Nest Bistro', 49.1687063,-123.9411687, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Fiddlehead Bistro', 49.1636625,-123.943215, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Sushi Nana', 49.1637405,-123.9382261, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['White Sails Brewery', 49.1700116,-123.9419486, 'cafes & restaurants'],
    ['Nanaimo Art Gallery', 49.1663609,-123.9388647, 'recreation'],
    ['The Port Theatre', 49.1658812,-123.9376841, 'recreation'],
    ['Vancouver Island Regional Library', 49.1642062,-123.9502371, 'recreation'],
    ['Nanaimo Museum', 49.1660304,-123.9382392, 'recreation'],
    ['Casino Nanaimo', 49.1646693,-123.9370797, 'recreation'],
    ['Harbourfront & The Bastion', 49.1670554,-123.9378173, 'recreation'],
    ['Maffeo Sutton Park', 49.1708949,-123.9408113, 'recreation'],
    ['Breakout Nanaimo Escape Rooms', 49.165459,-123.9418323, 'recreation'],
    ['OmTown Yoga', 49.1650315,-123.9393309, 'recreation'],
    ['Discovery Community College', 49.1630353,-123.9400086, 'other'],
    ['Sprott Shaw College', 49.1680883,-123.9418664, 'other'],
    ['H&R Block', 49.1679903,-123.9416508, 'other'],
    ['Canada Post', 49.1676141,-123.9406346, 'other'],
    ['Service Canada', 49.1684978,-123.9387041, 'other']
];
var markerColours = {'transportation':'#7ac1a3','financial services':'#dec978','nightlife':'#204572','shopping':'#d5797c','cafes & restaurants':'#06a3b6','recreation':'#e98547','accommodations':'#96b6c5','other':'#c7a285'};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
var icon = {
    path: 'M 0, 0 m -15, 0 a 15,15 0 1,0 30,0 a 15,15 0 1,0 -30,0',
    fillColor: '#7ac1c3',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0)
  };
function buildMap(locations, marker, filter){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.1677015,-123.940314),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
        if(typeof filter === 'undefined' || locations[i][3]==filter){
            icon.fillColor = markerColours[locations[i][3]]; 
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                //icon: icon,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

    }
}
buildMap(locations,marker);
$('.filter li').click(function(){
    var filter = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    console.log(filter);
    buildMap(locations,marker,filter);
})
```

});

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site that exhibits the issue.  Please also indicate _where_ the markers should be (or make your MCVE such that it is obvious).

Comment: Where did you get the location data from?

Comment: The Places API returns (49.16607,-123.930666) for the Gabriola Island Ferry Terminal, you have different coordinates (49.1661015, -123.932839).

Comment: Thank you, it does seem the location data was incorrect. I pulled it from the URL when searching the location in Google maps.

Comment: I'm guessing you got the coordinates from a Google Maps URL, where the coordinates after the @ sign are the center of the map, not the location you searched for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really looks like you provided the wrong coordinates. I tried the coordinates you provided in the first line `49.1661015,-123.932839`: and used Google maps. The location is [exactly the same](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/49%C2%B009'58.0%22N+123%C2%B055'58.2%22W/@49.1661015,-123.9350277,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d49.1661015!4d-123.932839) as where your marker is.

The [correct coordinates](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/49%C2%B009'58.1%22N+123%C2%B055'50.8%22W/@49.166147,-123.9318573,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d49.166147!4d-123.930763) should be more like `49.166147, -123.930763`

Comment: It's so weird, as I am pulling these coordinates straight from Google Maps, using the "what's here" right click, then copying the coordinates...

Comment: Looks like you are right...when I search one of these markers, copy the coordinates provided, and paste them back in, they are not at the point I just copied them from. What gives with Google? Is there a better way to get coordinates?

Comment: It worked for me on Google maps, but I tried on Bing maps and you can rightclick a location and choose `copy` from the dialog. Seems to work fine.

Comment: Looks like a beautiful location BTW